# How to select specific Child Node in HTML Dom with JQuery Selectors?

Tags: jquery, dom

I have these two HTML DOM examples and i want to know, how i can navigate to each checkbox, if i start my traversing at the node ?

DOM Example One:

```
<div class="box1 margin">
    <h3>Some Checkboxes</h3>
       <input type="checkbox">
       Nr. 1
       <br>
       <input type="checkbox">
       Nr. 2
       <br>
       <input type="checkbox">          
</div>
```

DOM Example Two:

```
<div>
   <h3>Some Checkboxes </h3>
     <div class="box1 margin">       
         <input type="checkbox">
         Nr. 1
         <br>
         <input type="checkbox">
         Nr. 2
         <br>
         <input type="checkbox">          
     </div>
     <div class="box1 margin">
        <input type="checkbox">
        Nr. 3
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox">
        Nr. 4
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox">          
     </div>
</div>
```

With navigate to each checkbox i mean the selection of this element and i want to select the checkbox !

Comment: what do you mean by navigate through each checkbox.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **each()** function of jquery

Following code may help you..

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('.box1').children('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
    console.log($(this));
  });
});
```

Comment: If have written this code to how it doesn´t selected the checboxes?: jQuery('.box2 margin').find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
  jQuery(this).prop('checked', true);    
 });

Comment: Why you use selector '.box2 margin'?
Please use only '.box2'.
That Means your code should look like this..
jQuery('.box2').find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() { jQuery(this).prop('checked', true); });

Comment: Thanks ! I get the information, that prop() is not a function?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the class `.box1` to target the `div` then use [descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) along with [element](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/) and [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to find the checkboxes. The use [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate through each of them

```
$('.box1 input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
    //this refers to the checkbox
    console.log(this)
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/k9AT9/)

To select the checkbox set the `checked` property to true like

```
$('.box1 input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/k9AT9/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Directly you can access `$('input[type="checkbox"]').each()`

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
   console.log(this.checked);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate through each checkbox for each `.box1.margin` container, simply use:

```
$('div.box1.margin').find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
    console.log(this.checked);
    ...
});
```

Or:

```
$('div.box1.margin input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
    console.log(this.checked);
    ...
});
```

Alternatively if you want to iterate through every checkbox on your page, instead use:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
    console.log(this.checked);
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery `each()` method , it iterates over the DOM elements that are part of the jQuery object.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   $('div.box1 input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
      console.log($(this).prop("checked")); 
   });
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/kKxze/)

Documentation : http://api.jquery.com/each/